# Автоматическое повышение версии OpenGL ES при публикации приложения

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, opengles

Разрабатываю некий проект. В Google Play уже есть его публикация *с версией кода 48* и *версией OpenGL ES 1.0+*.
Недавно внес некие поправки в проект и решил обновить приложение в Google Play. В итоге, я получил предупреждение о том что **не все устройства поддерживают новую версию OpenGL ES**, а именно **2.0+**. Детали отображены на скрине:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге, у меня возник вопрос: **почему поменялась версия OpenGL ES (с 1.0 на 2.0)**? В проекте особо не было никаких правок, только изменил версию приложения в Gradle и особо больше ничего не делал. Или данная версия зависит от конкретных свойств в проекте которые я мог случайно поменять?

Буду очень признателен за обьяснение.

Comment: Может Вы добавили какую то графику в проект? Например где то графически отобразили линию или фигуру. P.S. Версия 2.0 поддерживается с Android 2.2 (API level 8), поэтому процент устройств не поддерживающих данную версию крайне мал.

Comment: @Pollux, да, это я читал в документации. Просто интересно стало, что могло повысить версию OpenGL ES. Возможно вы правы на счет того, что добавил новую графику. Просто до этого тоже было много графических файлов, а версия оставалась 1.0.

Comment: Возможно, Вы использовали некоторый класс для рисования, который появился только в 2.0, а до этого обходились классами из 1.0, соответственно автоматически повысилось требование на выходе проекта. Более подробно можете посмотреть [тут](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl)

Comment: @Pollux, спасибо большое, все понятно.

Comment: тогда добавлю как ответ, чтобы закрыть вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может Вы добавили какую то графику в проект? Например где то графически отобразили линию или фигуру. P.S. Версия 2.0 поддерживается с Android 2.2 (API level 8), поэтому процент устройств не поддерживающих данную версию крайне мал.

Возможно, Вы использовали некоторый класс для рисования, который появился только в 2.0, а до этого обходились классами из 1.0, соответственно автоматически повысилось требование на выходе проекта. Более подробно можете посмотреть [тут](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl)